# Unable to Access RDS with JDBC in AWS

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, amazon-web-services

I am finding hard time connecting to RDS using JDBC connection, I am able to connect through MYSQL workbench, I deployed my WAR file in A WSwhich is running tomcat, this WAR file has my JDBCcode connecting to RDS, but I am not even able to establish connection.
My code is as below:-

```
public static Connection getconnection(){

     String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://testinstance.cj3ixhryi3fb.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/testDB";
        String dbUser = "testuser";
        String dbPwd = "usertest";
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, dbUser, dbPwd);
            System.out.println("conn Available");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("fetch otion error"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return conn;
}
```

I included all the necessary jar files, and rules security groups but no luck.

**I am using the EC2 security group for RDS. Does RDS will use ec2 security groups?**
or I need to have different security group for RDS?

the testinstance is a working link if any one wanna test.

Comment: Where is the Tomcat server? In Amazon EC2 or elsewhere? Amazon RDS instances are protected by Security Groups. You need to ensure your Security Group is set up correctly.

Comment: @GarrethMcDaid yes tomcat is in EC2, in security groups gave all permission also Added my IP for MYSQl rule

Comment: It could be that your instance is in a VPC and your RDS isn't set up with a VPC subnet.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your instance is in a VPC and your RDS instance isn't set up in a VPC subnet group.

If you want to connect to an RDS instance from a server instance in a VPC, your RDS instance has to be deployed in a VPC subnet.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.CreateDBSubnetGroup.html